# Why does my extension method does not cancel my task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, extension-methods

In UWP I wrote the following method in the model view:

```
 private async Task RFIDRead()
    {
        try
        {
            await nur_reader.SetupRFIDReader();
            string RFID_tag = await ProdSysCommon.ExtensionMethods.TimeoutAfter(nur_reader.PerformRFIDReading(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog("No RFID found in time, please scan again");
            dialog.Title = "Timeout Warning";
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

The extension method that I use is the following:

```
public static async Task<TResult> TimeoutAfter<TResult>(this Task<TResult> task, TimeSpan timeout)
    {

        using (var timeoutCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {

            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout, timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token));
            if (completedTask == task)
            {
                timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                return await task;  // Very important in order to propagate exceptions
            }
            else
            {
                throw new TimeoutException("The operation has timed out.");
            }
        }
    }
```

After I run this, I catch the timeout exception, but the nur_reader.PerformRFIDReading() keeps running. What do I do wrong with my extension method? How shall I change it, so it cancels the task?

Comment: The `TimeoutAfter` extension method cancels the awaiting of the task, not the task itself. After the awaiting has been canceled, the task continues running unobserved in the background, in a fire-and-forget fashion.

Comment: Ah, that makes senes!

Comment: Could you please tell has your problem been resolved?

Comment: I am currently looking to implement an alternative solution, so the issue is not yet resolved, but the reason for my issue is known.